# Jquery autocomplete font: change font in the box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

I am new to jquery.
I am exploring the autocomplete feature of jquery.
I was able to change the font of the dropdown list, but while I am unale to change the font of the field itself.
How do I change that?

Thank you.

```
 .ui-autocomplete.ui-widget {
      font: 400 1.5em/125% 'Sofia', Helvetica, Sans-serif;
      cursor: default;
      height: 200px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
  }

  .ui-autocomplete.ui-menu{
      font: 400 1.5em/125% 'Sofia', Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  }

  #input autocomplete {
      font: 400 1.5em/125% 'Sofia', Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  }


  .input{
    font: 400 1.5em/125% 'Sofia', Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

How does your HTML look like?

Does the input have any id or class?

you have:

```
.input{
    font: 400 1.5em/125% 'Sofia', Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  }
```

which means your input has class 'input'
I think you wanted to do something like:

```
input{
    font: 400 1.5em/125% 'Sofia', Helvetica, Sans-serif;
}
```

Note: I removed the dot '.' from the selector